# How to save multiple value of a single key in python

Tags: python

I want to save multiple values of a single key in python

```py
row = {
    [host_name, user_name, machine, node, Release, version],
    [ifaces],
    [get_network_mac(ifaces)],
}
```

```py
row = {
    [host_name, user_name, machine, node, Release, version],
    [ifaces],
    [get_network_mac(ifaces)],
}

print(row)
index = 2
sheet.insert_row(row, index)
```

this what I got from error.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script_interface.py", line 88, in <module>
    [get_network_mac(ifaces)],
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: As it is in your code, row is not a dictionary is a set, so you do not have any keys. In the other hand a list cannot be key, not be stored in a dictionary because they are not hashable (as in the message). I suggest you use a tuple.

Comment: Are you trying to save a dictionary that uses these lists (`[host_name, user_name, machine, node, Release, version]`, `[ifaces]`...)as keys? As Daniel says lists cannot be keys in a dict

Comment: @totooooo yeah I want to add all these values as a dictionary

Comment: Alright, but are you trying to use the lists as keys, or as values? I.e are you trying to do: 1/ this: `{[host_name, user_name, machine, node, Release, version]: some_value}` 2/ or this: `{some_key: [host_name, user_name, machine, node, Release, version]}`. As others pointed out, 1/ is not possible, although replacing the list with a tuple would be possible: 3/ `{(host_name, user_name, machine, node, Release, version): some_value}`

Answer (score 0):

```
key_is = "foo"
host_name = "..."
user_name = " ..."
machine = "..."
node = "..."
Release = "..."
version = "..."
ifaces = "ifaces"
get_network_mac = "network_mac"

host_name = ""
row = {key_is: ((host_name, user_name, machine, node, Release, version),
ifaces, get_network_mac)}

print(row[key_is])
#index = 2
#sheet.insert_row(row, index)
```

Comment: TypeError: Object of type function is not JSON serializable
I got this error on this line ```sheet.insert_row(row, index)```

Comment: I wrote it only to attach multiple variable to single key. Can you give more information or code snipped of `sheet.insert_row(row, index)`?

Answer (score 0):

You have created a Set and not a Dictionary.

Dictionary contains `{ key : value }` pairs. Keys must be an hashable, value can be any type.

On the other hand, Set contains values only (it is similar to list, but it is not ordered and it contains distinct values only).

List on python are not hashable so they cannot be keys in dictionary.

```py
a_set = {"a", "b", "c"}
a_dict = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
a_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: On a side note, you can use Sets has dictionary keys `my_dict = { (1, 2): "Test" }`